# dojo-data-type is not working

Tags: javascript, html, dojo, dijit.form

Guys am unable to use the dijit widgets in HTML5 code.
Its working completely fine with the legacy code `dojoType`. What is wrong with the HTML5 code ?

```
<!DOCTYPE >
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="js/dijit/themes/tundra/tundra.css">
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/dojo/dojo.xd.js" data-dojo-config="async: true"></script>
 <script type="text/javascript">
    dojo.require("dojo.parser");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Form");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.Button");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.ValidationTextBox");
    dojo.require("dijit.form.DateTextBox");
  </script>
</head>
<body class="tundra">
  <table style="border: 1px solid black;">
    <tr>
      <td>Name:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="name" name="name"
                 data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" /></td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
      <td>Date of birth:</td>
      <td><input type="text" id="dob" name="dob"
                 data-dojo-type="dijit.form.DateTextBox" /></td>
    </tr>
  </table>
  <input type="button" name="submitButton" value="Submit" />
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: What version of Dojo?

Answer (score 0):

> As of Dojo 1.8, the parser accepts a Module ID (MID) for the type.
>   Previously it accepted the declared class name of the object. It also
>   accepts anything that is declared in the global scope

So

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"
        data-dojo-type="dijit.form.ValidationTextBox" />
```

should be

```
<input type="text" id="name" name="name"
        data-dojo-type="dijit/form/ValidationTextBox" />
```

http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/dojo/parser.html#id8

Comment: Your data-dojo-config value says `async:true`, try replacing the `dojo.require()` calls as described in the [migration guide](http://dojotoolkit.org/reference-guide/1.9/releasenotes/migration-17.html).

Answer (score 0):

frameworks answer is deprecated legacy code from before dojo 1.6 !!!

1. read the migration guide or [this tutorial](https://dojotoolkit.org/documentation/tutorials/1.9/modern_dojo/)
2. In the original code

IF YOUR dojo IS 1.9 (as you commented), IT IS NOT LOADED

> **Prior to Dojo 1.7**, the cross-domain Dojo loader script was named dojo.xd.js

### REMOVE the .xd !

Add

```
parseOnLoad:    true
```

to dojoConfig (to be sure)

and change your dojo.require syntax to the correct one (see tutorial) :

```
require(["dojo/parser","dijit/form/Form", "ETC..."], function(){})
```